# Mapping URL to filesystem

Tags: nginx

What would be the best way to map this URL to this filesystem path?

From

```
http://site.com/200x300/ed3269d0-f9ef-4ffc-abea-5982969876c0/my file.jpg
```

To

```
/var/www/e/d/3/ed3269d0-f9ef-4ffc-abea-5982969876c0/200x300.jpg
```

Where

- "200x300" is the **size** of the image
- "ed3269d0-f9ef-4ffc-abea-5982969876c0" is the **guid** of the image
- "my file" is the name of the file (used for SEO, may contain spaces)
- "e", "d" and "3" are the **first 3 letters** of the guid
- ".jpg" is the **extension** of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like following:

```
location / {
   location ~* ^/(\d+x\d+)/((\w)(\w)(\w)[-\w]+)/[^/]+\.jpg$ {
      alias /var/www/$3/$4/$5/$2/$1.jpg;
   }
}
location /some_other_location/ { ... }
```

Comment: Why the use of a location inside of another location?

Comment: In case you have other non-regex locations (/some_other_location/ in my example) you'll be sure that they would not be mapped by regex location by mistake. Also, /some_other_location/ requests won't be checked by this regex and their processing would be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up (as I need to extract the extension too):

```
server {
   root /var/www;

   location ~* ^/(\d+x\d+)/((\w)(\w)(\w)[-\w]+)/[^\.]+\.(\w+)$ {
      try_files /$3/$4/$5/$2/$1.$6 /index.html;
   }
}
```